# Changing music on youtube video with data api

Tags: python, video, heroku, amazon-web-services, youtube-api

I have a task to automate process of adding music to youtube videos. User can choose music for the video and upload it to youtube. Basically, a simple web app:

- Login with OAuth
- Pick music
- Add it to youtube video (a new one or existing one)

I've looking at api, but it seems `update` can only change metadata. Is creating the new video only possible way?

Process:

- Login, pick music and upload video
- video is uploaded to S3
- When it's done one of workers kicks in to replace the music
- with user token video ends up on youtube

I've already implemented OAuth bit. Ideally I'd delegate the uploading to youtube and just swap/add the music, but that's not possible, is it?

Comment: There is no way to simply replace the video file of an existing video object; you can only create a new video and delete the old one (generating a new ID in the process). This is true for both the API and the YouTube website.

Comment: @jlmcdonald thanks. I really just need to replace the music. The functionality exists there, but sadly no API.